# PDO Laravel convert int to strings

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, pdo

I am having a problem that I have already seen published, but no solution has worked for me.

The system is in Laravel, and my problem is that when I retrieve records that have int data, the results of the api arrive in string.

Finding out that this is due to a flag ATTR_STRINGIFY_FETCHES , which must be false to avoid this behavior, I configured it and it worked fine in local (if it reads true in local it converts everything to string).

When I run tinker from the server and put something like
gettyp(result->integervalue), the value is integer, but if I do the same from a controller (only for testing peers), the type remains integer.

It is a vps server with cpanel that uses Apache for this, I know as if the db configuration will not be applied.

My laravel config mysql configuration

[configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fy2u5.png)

Php version 8.1
PDO Driver for MySQL => enabled

I really don't know what I'll do anymore, it seems super strange that when I use tinker the data is represented as I expect, but when it is represented through the Laravel code, that's how the configuration will not be applied.

An alternative is to force cast all types, but the project is very large and we are trying to avoid doing this.

Does anyone have any idea how to solve this?

Activate flags to force ints to be preserved, but it doesn't work

Comment: which solutions have you test and what was the error

Comment: PDO::ATTR_STRINGIFY_FETCHES => false,
                PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false


There is simply no error, when I use php artsan tinker, it is reflected as shown, but when I consult the api through Apache, eloquent transforms the int to string, I think something has to do with the controller, but I don't know what else to do or change.